# How to load records dynamically in listview

Tags: android, listview

Hi i am very new for android and in my case i have 200 above records i have to show in my list-view so it's burdon to load all records at a time that's why i request to `server` `offset value` then based on offset value server sending records then i am displaying `records` for this i wrote below code but `duplicate records` also adding in my `ArrayList` how can we resolve ?

my code is below very clearly and i am sending server link also please help me

### code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private int scrollState;
    private int offset = 0;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean loadingMore = false;
    ProgressBar pb;
    private int scrollpos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            arrayList = (ArrayList<String>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
        }

        //Adding footer for ListView:-
        pb = new ProgressBar(this);
        lv.addFooterView(pb);

        //Setting Adapter:-
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (!flag) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
            flag = true;
        }

        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                MainActivity.this.scrollState = scrollState;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                 int totalItemCount) {

                scrollpos = totalItemCount;
                int lastPos = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                if (lastPos == totalItemCount && !loadingMore) {

                    if (totalItemCount < 250) {
                        new loadMoreListView().execute();
                    } else {
                        lv.removeFooterView(pb);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("list", arrayList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
    }

    private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            loadingMore = true;
            String result = null;
            String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/imdb_top_250.php?offset=" + offset;
            try {
                URL mUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String str = "";
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(str);
                }
                result = buffer.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println("Result is"+result);

            if (result != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        arrayList.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                    }

                    System.out.println("arry list count is====>"+arrayList.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    offset++;
                   // offset = offset + 10;
                    loadingMore = false;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                lv.removeFooterView(pb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also get same problem use this code. It's remove your old data

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
arrayList.clear();
        System.out.println("Result is"+result);

        if (result != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    arrayList.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                }

                System.out.println("arry list count is====>"+arrayList.size());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                offset++;
               // offset = offset + 10;
                loadingMore = false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            lv.removeFooterView(pb);
        }
    }
```

**Edit code**
I check your code. Your json data is problem, 
Otherwise your Java coding is perfect.
You have totally 20 records.
Every time you send a offset data 1, 2, 3, etc
That time you remove offset value record.(Eg: offset 3 to remove 1-3 record).
Change your json coding it will work perfect.

Comment: then u understnad what is problem

Comment: Once check data available or not. If data available to use arrayList.clear();

Comment: if ur free i will let my sample code through google drive

Comment: Yeah sure I will check

Comment: ur using android studio?

Comment: Yes I am using android studio

Comment: please download and check once

Comment: It's ok no problem

Comment: Code is downloading now. I will update with in 30 min or 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one condition. Replace this method with yours.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println("Result is"+result);

            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    if(arrayList.size>0)
                    {
                      arrayList.clear();
                    }
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        arrayList.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                    }

                    System.out.println("arry list count is====>"+arrayList.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    offset++;
                   // offset = offset + 10;
                    loadingMore = false;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                lv.removeFooterView(pb);
            }
        }
    }
```